# If $f\in L[0,2\pi]$ and $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}|\bar{f}|^{2}<\infty$, then $f\in L^{2}[0,2\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f\in L[0,2\pi]$ and $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f}|^{2}<\infty$, then $f\in L^{2}[0,2\pi]$.

Attempt

We have $F(f)\in l^{2}$, where F is the Fourier transform. But we get stuck because unitarity is only for $L^{2}[\mathbb{R}]$.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

$F(f)\in l^{2}[0,2\pi]$ so by Parsevals, there is a function $g\in L^{2}$ s.t. $g(x)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(k)e^{2\pi ik x}$. For this space, $L^{2}\subset L^{1}\Rightarrow g\in L^{1}$. Thus, by uniqueness of Fourier coefficients, $f=g\in L_{2}$.